# Using powershell how to know which sharepoint group has what permissions and permissions level

Tags: 2013, powershell

from power shell how to know which sharepoint group has what permissions and permissions level in a sharepoint 2013 site collection.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by using below power shell script :

```
$sites = get-spsite "site url"
foreach ($site in $sites)
{

write-host -foregroundcolor green "Working on Site Collection: "$site.RootWeb.Title "..."
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) 
 {
  foreach($roleAssignment in $web.RoleAssignments)
  {
write-host -foregroundcolor green "Group Name: "$roleAssignment.Member.Name "..."

       foreach($roleDefinition in $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
            {
                write-host -foregroundcolor red "Permission Name: "$roleDefinition.Name "..."
            }

  }

 }
  $web.Dispose()
}

$site.Dispose()
```

please refer the link for more info on power shell scripts operations on SharePoint User and Groups :http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-2013/exploring-sharepoint-users-groups-and-security-using-powershell

Comment: thanks, i want to know permissions for given user or usrsgroup only?

Answer (score 0):

```
 #$path = get-location
 $sites = get-spsite "http://SP2010/site/sam/"
 foreach ($site in $sites)
 {
  write-host -foregroundcolor green "Working on Site Collection:"$site.RootWeb.Title "..."

  foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) 
   {
    foreach($roleAssignment in $web.RoleAssignments)
     {
       write-host -foregroundcolor green "Group Name:"$roleAssignment.Member.Name    
 "..."

   foreach($roleDefinition in $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
            {
                write-host -foregroundcolor red "Permission Name: "$roleDefinition.Name "..."
            }

  }

 }
   $web.Dispose()}}  
$site.Dispose()
```

[Article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6c502cd5-04a0-4b9e-a35a-dd7e9cd6d431/get-permission-levels-of-a-sharepoint-group-using-powershell-script-?forum=sharepointadminprevious)